# Svg color transition on mouseover with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an "svg" tag in my html, this is a soundcloud icon. I would like the soundcloud icon to transition colors on mouseover as if I was using the "transition" property in CSS. You can take a look at the twitter bootstrap icons on either side of the soundcloud icon in the link below to see what I mean.

I have tried this with no luck:

```
$(".soundcloud")
.mouseenter(function() {
var color = "#ff7700";
$(this).animate({children().css('fill',color); 
}, 1000) })
.mouseleave(function() {
$(this).animate({children().css('fill','#FAFAFA');
}, 1000)});
});
```

The site is hosted here: http://itstonygraham.com/archive/dev/

A version of this script is before the closing body tag.

How would I got about making something like this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you would consider using css3, have a look at this blog post from Adobe about animating svgs

http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/03/30/svg-animations-css-animations-css-transitions/

Basically just applying the animation class on hover and then some

Comment: I have came across that article before. The problem is that when I hover over the icon the color changes to purple but it does not stay purple. How would I make the icon color stay purple as long as the mouse is over the icon?                                                                                                                   
<animate attributeName="fill" from="#FAFAFA" to="purple"
        dur="0.45s" begin="mouseover"/>

Comment: Try using jquery's on function 

    $("button").on("mouseover", function(){
      $("div").animate({left:'250px'});
    });